# From Insertion Point select a word in Font Kruti Dev 010 that contains Full Stop Mark (.)

Tags: vba, select, fonts, ms-word, insertion

Is there not any way to tell MSWord that it take FullStopMark (.) for letter 'n' and Letter 'A' for 'FullStopMark (.) during a Procedure.  This I want because this is a word in Font "Kruti Dev 010". This Procedure selects the word upto before the full stop mark. I want it to select it upto last 'k'.

> **jke'kj.kA**

```vb
Sub SelectFromIBeam()
    Selection.Words(1).Select
End Sub
```

```
    Sub SelectHindi()
    Selection.StartOf Unit:=wdWord, Extend:=wdExtend
    x = Selection.MoveEndUntil(Cset:="A", Count:=wdForward) _
            Or Selection.MoveEndUntil(Cset:=" ", Count:=wdForward) _
            Or Selection.MoveEndUntil(Cset:=vbCr, Count:=wdForward)
    Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    End Sub
```

I want MoveEndUntil to perform the task whatever condition is met first of the above 3.

Comment: You will most likely have to write some code using moveenduntil. Cset would contain the characters you want to find e.g. 'Kk'.  If you need to find the last cset character in a selection you will need to move the end backwards

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this. Although I am not much familier about word vba.

Comment: @ Timothy Rylatt Thanks for guiding me.